# Java lottery fill array

Tags: java, arrays, fill

Here's the code:

```
 public void playMany() {

    for (int i = 0; i < lotteryNumbers.length; i++) {
        lotteryNumbers[i] = 0 + r.nextInt(9);

    }


    for (int i = 0; i < playersNumbers.length; i++) {

        playersNumbers[i] = 0 + r.nextInt(9);

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < lotteryNumbers.length; i++) {
        if (lotteryNumbers[i] == playersNumbers[i]) {
            winNum++;

        }
    }
   if (winNum == 0) {
        winningNum[0]++;
    }
    if (winNum == 1) {
        winningNum[1]++;
    }
    if (winNum == 2) {
        winningNum[2]++;
    }
    if (winNum == 3) {
        winningNum[3]++;
    }
    if (winNum == 4) {
        winningNum[4]++;
    }
    if (winNum == 5) {
        winningNum[5]++;
    }
   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(winningNum));
    }

}
```

With this method I want to play one draw of lottery with so many playerNumbers it takes until every index in playersNumbers and lotteryNumbers is the same. I want to save every result in winningNum so I can see how many times I hit 0, 1, 2, 3 etc. Now it plays only one time and stores it in the array. I tried with loops and boolean to play many times but I cant get it to work

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question but you could optimize it so that instead of 5 if statements they could be replaces with just `winningNum[winNum]++`.

Comment: What happens if none of the numbers in lotteryNumbers and playerNumbers match?

Comment: I was actually looking for that to, I will change that. With this method I want to play one draw of lottery with so many playerNumbers it takes until every index in playersNumbers and lotteryNumbers is the same. I want to save every result in winningNum so I can see how many times I hit 0, 1, 2, 3 etc. Now it plays only one time and stores it in the array. I tried with loops and boolean to play many times but I cant get it to work

Comment: @chancea Then array winningNum index 0 ++

Comment: If you look at my answer, you need a "getNumber" method that makes sure the same number is not drawn twice. You also need to use Array.Sort to get the numbers in the correct order.

Comment: You need to compare each palyer number with each lottery number or use a different/better data structure, like a collection where you can call intersect().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try{
        int[] lotteryNumbers = new int[5];
        int[] playersNumbers = new int[5];
        int[] winningNum = new int[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
        int winNum = 0;
        Random r = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < lotteryNumbers.length; i++){
                lotteryNumbers[i] = 0 + r.nextInt(9);
        }
        do{
            winNum = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < playersNumbers.length; i++){
                playersNumbers[i] = 0 + r.nextInt(9);

            }

            for (int i = 0; i < lotteryNumbers.length; i++){
                if (lotteryNumbers[i] == playersNumbers[i]){
                    winNum++;
                }
            }
            winningNum[winNum]++;
        }while(winNum != 5);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(winningNum));
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I think this is what you were looking for, if you want some of it explained, please just leave a comment - note that the winningNum array is size 6 - because you can get 0-4 correct for each tieration + the final one where you win leaves 6 options

Comment: if you run the code above, your output will be exactly what i think you expect: [32628, 20018, 5012, 603, 41, 1]
32628 'tickets' with 0 winning numrbers, 20018 with 1, etc

Comment: I worked with this for two days on many different ways. It gave me the same result all the time. I was forgetting to set the winNum=0; before every loop. It seems always to be about really little things thats wrong and Im alway trying to hard.